# Prove projection of convex hull = convex hull of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, integer-programming, projection, convex-hulls

I'm not sure how to show this:

$proj_x(conv(S)) = conv(proj_x(S))$ where S $\in R^{n+p}$

Comment: What is $proj_x$? (What is $x$?)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a point in the projection of $conv(S)$ and, using the definition of convex hull, show it is in convex hull of the projection of $S$. Then take a point in the convex hull of the projection of $S$ and, again using the definition of convex hull, show it is in the projection of $conv(S)$.